# How do you write an extension to support both [String] and [Substring]?

Tags: swift, swift4, swift-extensions

Normally, to write an extension against a `[String]`, you do this...

```
extension Array where Element == String {
    ....
}
```

However, sometimes I don't have a `[String]` but rather a `[Substring]`.  How can you write an extension that supports either?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `String` and `Substring` conform to the `StringProtocol` protocol,
so you can define

```
extension Array where Element: StringProtocol {
    // ...
}
```

Many functions from the standard library have been generalized
to take `StringProtocol` arguments, for example the `Int`
initializer

```
convenience init?<S>(_ text: S, radix: Int = default) where S : StringProtocol
```

so that you can call it with both a `String` and a `Substring`:

```
let n = Int("1234")
let m = Int("1234".dropFirst())
```